# Environment.FailFast in a web context

Tags: .net

Does a System.Environment.FailFast http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx usage has any sens in a web applications ?

It kills a process and I can't figure out how it could be applied in the web context.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: No, it makes no sense what so ever. I am not sure it ever makes sense to use it anywhere. Except maybe in a missile launching application that is running astray.

Comment: LOL ;) It what comes to my mind first :)

Comment: I agree with the above. Thomas - perhaps instead of coming up with artificial scenarios you should be spending your time contributing documentation to some open source projects?

Comment: It's the recommandation from Framework Design Guidelines by Krzysztof Cwalina ;)

Comment: Krzysztof, I would prefer to code, that to write documentation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unswer to my own question.

From discussions, I consider that it has no applicability at all.